# iOS Provisioning Profile Renewal Process with MDM

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, mdm, ios-enterprise, intune

I have an Enterprise app that was distributed through MDM.How I can handle 
provisioning profile renewal process for the apps that are distributed through MDM? Do I need to release an app update using the new provisioning profile every time whenever it got expired or is there any way I can handle it automatically through MDM (without releasing the new app update)?

Comment: I know if it possible with some MDM products.  I haven't been able to find a way to do it in BES 12, Blackberry's MDM product, though.  We've had to rebuild / re-sign the apps and push new versions.  This seems like a waste, since the app will work fin if we could just get the new profile on the device.  Which MDM product are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Intune MDM.But I didn't get any documentation regarding profile push through MDM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is possible with Microsoft Intune.  Per the documentation, you create a new Mobile Provisioning Profile Policy, import the .mobileprovision file, and apply the new policy to the devices.

Full details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/app-provisioning-profile-ios).

Comment: Thanks wottle..will check it